# cPanel Distorted w/ 401 Error on CSS/Images

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting

This is very strange behavior. My cPanel is looking very distorted when I log in from mydomain.com/cpanel but is fine if logged in through <server ip>/cpanel. When I use Chrome to check for errors I see some CSS and images are getting the 401 error. Below is a screenshot of my cPanel. I called tech support and they weren't able to answer my question and help me fix the situation!  Not sure if CloudFlare has anything to do with it, but I did install it three days before this post was up.  I went into CloudFlare and make sure cPanel is bypass.

[Distorted CPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqZ7c.jpg)

Bump! Will put out bounty soon!

Comment: Are you accessing via HTTPS when logging in through `<server ip>/cpanel`? And plain HTTP when accessing through your domain?

Comment: Not access through HTTPS, but I did install CloudFlare two days ago.  However, on CloudFlare cPanel is bypass so it shouldn't go through CloudFlare at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by CloudFlare.  For whatever reason CloudFlare would put you into a loop when you attempt to login to your cPanel with www.yourdomain.com/cpanel.  The fix is simply place a direct in from of your domain name such as direct.yourdomain.com/cpanel and it would fix this issue or per CloudFlare.com [Accessing cPanel with CloudFlare](https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22047603-how-do-i-use-cpanel-with-cloudflare).  Thanks for all that responded.